# over sampling before or after categorical encoding?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, classification, predictive-models, random-forest

I understand that class imbalance is not considered as a problem by the users here. But for the sake of experimentation, I would like to try out the oversampling for my data (which is of 77:23 proportion).

I am working on a binary classification problem using traditional ML algos and neural networks.

As most of my variables are categorical and highly cardinal in nature, I use encoding methods like `ordinal_encoder`, `rare_encoder` etc.

So, my question is

a) To balance my classes, should I oversample/undersample the class before categorical encoding or after categorical encoding?

can you also let me know the reason as to why it should be done the way you suggest (and not the other way round)?

Comment: How will you oversample?

Comment: @gunes. I will try SMOTE, Bagging classifier etc.

Comment: I can also try SMOTE-NC variant etc.

Comment: Can anyone help me with this?